# HTML Elements as While Conditions

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop, boolean, conditional-statements

I had a question about some code I ran into while learning how to code.

I wanted to know how it is possible for an HTML element to function as a boolean condition in a JavaScript while loop.

For example, let's say I have a HTML table and a while loop that points to the table:

HTML Table:

```
<table border="1" id="menuTable">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Random Data</td>
        <td>More Random Data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript Loop:

```
var Tags = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');

var Parent = Tags[0].parentNode; //so Parent should be the <td> tag 

//Here is where things get confusing for me...

function sampleFunction(){
    while (Parent) //How is THIS node a possible boolean condition? What's being evaluated?
    {  
        if (Parent.nodeName == "TR"){
            return Parent;
        }
        Parent = Parent.parentNode;  
    }
    return Parent;
}

//I understand that the while loop is supposed to return a <tr> tag after the loop runs...
//what I don't understand is how the <td> tag/Parent variable can operate as a condition.
```

I hope the question is clear.
I've been searching for an answer to this question for a while now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (Parent) //How is THIS node a possible boolean condition? What's being evaluated?`

In JavaScript, there are 2 tricky data types other than Booleans, Integers, Strings, Arrays, and Objects that you need to be aware of. This is the `undefined` and the `null` data types.

Basically what this `while (Parent)` is checking, is eqal to:

`Parent !== null && Parent !== undefined && Parent !== false`

If `Parent` has been assigned any value at this time, this expression will evaluate to `True`.

I've heard people coin this as checking "while `Parent` exists" because you could  potentially set a condition in your while loop that will set `Parent` to undefined or null or false to terminate the loop early.

So basically, while `Parent` exists, or while it is not `null` or `undefined` or `false`

Comment: undefined and null both evaluate to false

Comment: Thanks! So one more question. In my example, wouldn't the Parent tag be returned as soon as it is set to its own parent (after 
Parent = Parent.parentNode;)?
And wouldn't that also end the loop?

Comment: no changing the variable to another value won't exit the loop, inless its `null` `undefined`, `0`, or `false`, as soon as you `return Parent` it exits the function entirely

Comment: It's also checking for `Parent != ""` and `Parent !== 0`.